# How can I get more triggers for reaction attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, actions, dnd-adventurers-league

I have been considering making a character that is a very reactive combatant. I want it to be a character that makes as many opportunity attacks as possible, and I am wondering if anybody knows of any feats, abilities or traits that grant  additional reaction attack triggers, beyond the ones I am already familiar with. For example the fighter maneuver riposte adds, when a creature misses them (trigger), a player can expend a superiority die to make an attack.

So far I know of:

Situational:

- Moving out of threatened area

Feats:

- Mage Slayer
- Polearm Master
- Sentinel

Fighter:

- Riposte Maneuver

Comment: Are you asking for features that give you multiple triggers for possible attacks, or features that let you actually make multiple (off-turn) attacks? I'm guessing most such features use your reaction; you only get one reaction per round, and your reaction "refreshes" at the start of each of your turns.

Comment: It might be worth taking some time to investigate readying an action for some trigger, to get the flavour of that "reactive" fighter, without worrying so much about the limited mechanic surrounding the "Reaction" action.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Here are all the options officially released

(as of 5-3-2018) (*italics indicates that the feature must be used by an ally*)

### Class Features

- **Barbarian (Path of the Berserker):** Retaliation [PHB]
- ***Fighter (Battle Master):*** Combat Superiority: Commander's Strike [PHB]
- **Fighter (Battle Master):** Combat Superiority: Riposte [PHB]
- **Fighter (Cavalier):** Hold the Line [XGtE]
- ***Fighter (Banneret):*** Inspiring Surge [SCAG]
- **Monk (Way of Shadow):** Opportunist [PHB]
- **Paladin (Oath of Vengeance):** Soul of Vengeance [PHB]
- **Ranger (Hunter):** Hunter's Prey: Giant Killer [PHB]
- **Ranger (Monster Hunter):** Slayer's Counter [XGtE]

### Feats

- **Mage Slayer** [PHB]
- **Sentinel** [PHB]
- **Polearm Master** [PHB]
- **Orcish Fury** [XGtE]

### Incidental

- Standard opportunity attack [PHB]

### Monster forms/summons

- ***Gnoll Pack Lord:*** Incite Rampage [MM]
- ***Orc Blade of Ilneval:*** Ilneval's Command [VGtM]
- **Tanarukk:** Unbridled Fury [VGtM]
- ***Warlord:*** Command Ally [VGtM]
- **Gnoll Witherling:** Vengeful Strike [VGtM]
- **Hellenrae:** Parry and Counter [PotA]
- **Broom of Animate Attack:** Animated Attack [CoS]
- **Duergar Kavalrachni:** Cavalry Training [OotA]

### Multiple Reaction Attacks

While not strictly a feature that allows a reaction attack, the Fighter (Cavalier) is the only class that allows multiple opportunity attacks in one round with its level 18 feature **Vigilant Defender**.

(There are also a number of monsters that can use multiple reactions that I won't list as it is unlikely to be particularly useful since those monsters only can use standard opportunity attacks and you lose your class features and feats when under the effects of *true polymorph*)

---

<sup>PHB: Player's Handbook

XGtE: Xanathar's Guide to Everything

SCAG: Sword's Coast Adventurer's Gudie

MM: Monster Manual

PotA: Princes of the Apocalypse

CoS: Curse of Strahd

OotA: Out of the Abyss</sup>

*Note: Here is a useful source for looking at player options for Reaction; not just limited to reaction attacks and doesn't consider monsters, but it is a useful source (Thanks @V2Blast): [Master of Reactions - A Mini Guide](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?389171-Master-of-Reactions-%97-A-Mini-Guide)*

Comment: I'm not sure if the answer already contains all the relevant "reaction attacks" listed herein, but there is this forum post which claims to list every reaction-based Player Character ability in 5e so far: [Master of Reactions — A Mini-Guide](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?389171-Master-of-Reactions-%97-A-Mini-Guide) (Note that not all of the abilities listed in the forum post are actually attacks.)

Comment: @V2Blast I think I got them all, but that is a great source that I'll lin k in a note