# What bonus actions are available to all characters, regardless of class, race, feats, background, or other specific features?

Tags: dnd-5e, bonus-action

According to WotC-official sources, what bonus actions are available to every character in general, regardless of class, race, feats, background, or other specific features? That is, what bonus actions are available to any character, regardless of the choices you make during character creation and leveling up? For the sake of this question, let's say that equipment that isn't a magic item is okay to be a pre-requisite -- such as needing to have two light weapons.

Is there anything else beside [Two-Weapon Fighting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/combat#TwoWeaponFighting) and maybe [Casting a Spell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/spellcasting#BonusAction) with a casting time of 1 bonus action? (For the latter I say "maybe" because it's a general rule, though you can only take advantage of it if you have a spellcasting feature).

Comment: See also: [What reaction is available to all characters in general, regardless of class and race?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/116913/what-reaction-is-available-to-all-characters-in-general-regardless-of-class-and)

Comment: This is a neat question. The Cast a Spell action as a bonus action is definitely one that depends on having selected during creation or advancement a specific feature that grants it (or received it through some other boon), so I don’t think it qualifies here.

Comment: Are the epic boons mentioned in the Hobgoblin’s answer in the spirit of the question here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Core Rules

Two-Weapon Fighting:

> When you take the Attack action and attack with a light melee weapon that you’re holding in one hand, you can use a bonus action to attack with a different light melee weapon that you’re holding in the other hand. You don’t add your ability modifier to the damage of the bonus attack, unless that modifier is negative.

This is the only universally available bonus action appearing in the *Player's Handbook.*

### Optional Rules

These rules are all optional and come from chapter 9 of the *Dungeon Master's Guide*. They aren’t automatically available to all characters, unless the DM decides to use these optional rules, in which case they are available to use by everyone at any given time.

Healing Surge as a bonus action:

> This optional rule allows characters to heal up in the thick of combat and works well for parties that feature few or no characters with healing magic, or for campaigns in which magical healing is rare.
>
> As an action, a character can use a healing surge and spend up to half his or her Hit Dice. [...]
>
> For a more superheroic feel, you can let a character use a healing surge as a bonus action, rather than as an action.

Reloading a firearm with the Reload property (requires you to have a weapon with this property, similar to how TWF requires you to have two light weapons):

> ***Reload.*** A limited number of shots can be made with a weapon that has the reload property. A character must then reload it using an action or a bonus action (the character’s choice).

The Overrun optional action:

> When a creature tries to move through a hostile creature’s space, the mover can try to force its way through by overrunning the hostile creature. As an action or a bonus action, the mover makes a Strength (Athletics) check contested by the hostile creature’s Strength (Athletics) check. [...]

The Tumble optional action:

> A creature can try to tumble through a hostile creature’s space, ducking and weaving past the opponent. As an action or a bonus action, the tumbler makes a Dexterity (Acrobatics) check contested by the hostile creature’s Dexterity (Acrobatics) check. [...]

Comment: Well done, Thomas, to separate the core rules from the optional rules. +1.

Answer (score 3):

### Epic Level Boons

These are not selected by the player during character development, they are granted by the DM and are not generally dependent on class, race, feats nor are they magic items. The boon of Recovery and the Boon of Speed do not depend on any specific other features the character has, like Spellcasting.

For example the Boon of Speed says:

> Your walking speed increases by 30 feet. In addition, you can use a **bonus action** to take the Dash or Disengage action. Once you do so, you can't do
> so again until you finish a short rest.

Of course, you have to be 20th level to gain them, so in practice these are much less relevant than two-weapon fighting, overrun or tumble, or the more rarely used optional rules for reloading firearms or allowing healing surges in combat.

Comment: I excluded any bonus actions that came from being given something by the DM. Maybe Kerrick can weigh in on if these are in the spirit of the question?

Comment: Decided to go ahead and vote in the downward direction, I find it hard to reconcile “available to all characters” and “available to characters who have reached level 20, *then* gained enough experience to reach level 21, *then* been given one of the specific boons that grants a bonus action”. This answer really does not seem to be aligned with the spirit of the question.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I think there is a distinction between what is available to _every_ character (all characters have this option) and what is available to _any_ character (no character is excluded from this option based on race, class, background).  Unfortunately OP mixes the terms and hasn't yet told us which is relevant.

Comment: For what it's worth, you don't have to wait to level 20 to grant an epic boon as a DM ~ DM is the Master of Rules ~ but I'd need to look at the explicit language (AFB) to give you more feedback on this answer.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast the DMG does say explicitly "An epic boon is a special power available only to 20th level characters." Obviously any DM can ignore that and give them out whenever, but that's how it's described in the book. There is a RAW way to get one as early as 10th level through the Aberrant Dragonmark feat (though still at the discretion of the DM).

Comment: You're 6 upvotes away from 99,999 reputation!

Comment: @Justhalf Thanks for alerting me - right now I am at exactly 99,999 and thanks to you pointing it out to me, was able to make a screenshot of that special number

Comment: And now you're past 100k, congrats, haha.